# Traktor Audio 2 DJ soundcard configuration

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a [*Traktor Audio 2 DJ* USB sound card](http://www.native-instruments.com/#/en/products/dj/audio-2-dj/) (the first version of what it's now called simply *Traktor Audio 2*)

The problem in settings it only sees one output, when there should be two (I need that for Mixxx etc.)

Also I want to be able set the sample rate to one of these: 44.1, 48, 88.2, 96 kHz or at least check which one is set.

Additionally if possible setting the latency would be an advantage.

Some info:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: TraktorAudio2 [Traktor Audio 2], device 0: Traktor Audio 2 [Traktor Audio 2]
  Subdevices: 1/2
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfdcfc000 irq 45
1 [TraktorAudio2  ]: snd-usb-caiaq - Traktor Audio 2
                      Native Instruments Traktor Audio 2 (usb-0000:00:1d.7-8)
```

Comment: For those of you looking for the answer for the newer version of the Audio 2 DJ (the Audio 2): http://askubuntu.com/q/214749/9781

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you: [Audio2DJ, with Mixxx on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.native-instruments.com/forum/showthread.php?t=97903)

In summary, you need to create an `.asoundrc` file in your home folder with the following contents. Then you should be able to select each one of the channels (e.g. `djA`, `djB`, `djAB`) in your audio software's preferences (e.g. Mixxx).

```
#-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# Native Instruments :: Audio2DJ ALSA Configuration
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
#
#    device channels        ports
#    --------   ---             ---------
#    djA        2               12xx
#    djB        2               xx34
#
#    djAB       4               1234

#-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
# dj(a-d) :: Raw 1x1 Stereo Devices
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
pcm.djA { type plug; slave.pcm "hw:Audio2DJ,0,0"; }
pcm.djB { type plug; slave.pcm "hw:Audio2DJ,0,1"; }


# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
# djAB :: Multi 2x2 Stereo Device (Ports 1-4, Channels A+B)
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
pcm.djAB {
        type multi

        # bind hardware devices
        slaves.a.pcm djA
        slaves.a.channels 2
        slaves.b.pcm djB
        slaves.b.channels 2

        # bind channels to virtual device
        bindings.0.slave a
        bindings.0.channel 0
        bindings.1.slave a
        bindings.1.channel 1
        bindings.2.slave b
        bindings.2.channel 0
        bindings.3.slave b
        bindings.3.channel 1
}
```